# Order by last usage

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Java + Hibernate.

I have a few users and a table with companies. Users can list all companies and edit any company.

What is the best way to order companies by the last usage by the current user? So that every user sees companies he edited recently on the top of the list.

Comment: +1. But what is your database schema? Do you have two columns: `last_modified_date` and `last_modified_by_user_id` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the third table EditDate with columns: userId, companyId, lastEditDate. When selecting from companies of user join the EditData and order this by lastEditDate.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have created a class for companies, you could simply put in a member variable for last used date that updates any time the user accesses/updates the company.  give it an accessor method and use that to sort by.

Comment: Same as with @yogeshprajapati answer - read the question thoroughly.